# Open Server's console font not working right

Tags: conemu, terminal-emulator

After installing OS 5.2.8 Ultimate, Everything works, except that the text font is white and the text size is the same.
Image with a problem:
[image: Image whit console]

Comment: Font? Your composer doesn't output `\x1b` properly, it's not a ConEmu problem.

Comment: thanks for answer, but where search the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5323#issuecomment-220445695 On the composer site?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i added in composer.bat next code: php "%~dp0composer.phar" %* --no-ansi,  and ist' working for composer -v. But for laravel -v, is the same problem

Comment: I think it's PHP problem